# splitting a string into a phone number and extension using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, phone-number

So I'm trying to split a string that contains a phone number and extension, as sometimes an extension exists in the string. This is my attempt:

```
$tests[] = "941-751-6550 ext 2204";
$tests[] = "(941) 751-6550 ext 2204";
$tests[] = "(941)751-6550 ext 2204";
$tests[] = "9417516550 ext 2204";
$tests[] = "941-751-6550 e 2204";
$tests[] = "941-751-6550 ext 2204 ";
$tests[] = "941-751-6550 extension 2204";
$tests[] = "941-751-6550 x2204";
$tests[] = "(941) 751-6550";
$tests[] = "(941)7516550";
$tests[] = "941-751-6550 ";
$tests[] = "941-751-6550";

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    preg_match('#([\(\)\s0-9\-]+)(.+$)#',$test,$matches);
    $phone = preg_replace('#[\-\(\)\s]#','',$matches[1]);
    $extension = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#','',$matches[2]);
    if ($phone == '9417516550' 
        && ($extension == '2204' 
            || $extension == '0')) {
                echo "PASS: phone: $phone ext: $extension<br />";
    } else {
        echo "FAIL: phone: $phone ext: $extension<br />";
    }
}
```

However, when I run these tests to see if it properly splits the phone number and the extension, I get the following output:

```
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
FAIL: phone: 941751655 ext: 0
FAIL: phone: 941751655 ext: 0
FAIL: phone: 9417516550 ext: 
FAIL: phone: 941751655 ext: 0
```

As you can see, it breaks when I exclude an extension altogether (the last four tests). How might I correct the `preg_match()` regex so that the `FAIL: ...` lines look like `PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 0`?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use regex?

Comment: I guess you can reduce the regex, please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(.+$)` means that in the end of a line must be 1 or more symbol. So, if you have nothing after phone number - then your phone number is reduced by 1 symbol.

I advise to use `(.*$)` which means zero or more symbols.

Comment: This is it! I accepted your answer as you were the first to point out the non-greedy matching being the solution; the rest is just implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it all in the `preg_match`. Assuming the numbers are non-international I think this would work.

```
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    preg_match('#\(?(\d{3})\)?[-\h]?(\d{3})[-\h]?(\d{4})\h*(?:e?x?t?(?:ension)?\h(\d+))?#',$test,$matches);
    $phone = $matches[1] . $matches[2] . $matches[3];
    $extension = !empty($matches[4]) ? $matches[4] : 0;
    if ($phone == '9417516550' 
        && ($extension == '2204' || $extension == '0')) {
            echo "PASS: phone: $phone ext: $extension<br />";
    } else {
         echo "FAIL: phone: $phone ext: $extension<br />";
    }
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/561720
Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mG9iD1/1

Comment: Interesting, thank you. This is vastly different from what I was attempting but upvoted nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected, just tested.

```
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    preg_match('#([\(\)0-9\-]+\s*[\(\)0-9\-]+)\s*(.*$)#',$test,$matches);
    $phone = preg_replace('#[\-\(\)\s]#','',$matches[1]);
    $extension = ($matches[2] == "") ? '0' : preg_replace('#[^0-9]#','',$matches[2]);
    if ($phone == '9417516550'
        && ($extension == '2204'
            || $extension == '0')) {
                echo "PASS: phone: $phone ext: $extension<br />\n";
    } else {
        echo "FAIL: phone: $phone ext: $extension<br />\n";
    }
}
```

With minimal changes on your code.

Comment: This works, upvoted and thank you. I accepted @u_mulder 's answer as he came across the non-greedy solution first.

Comment: Ok but pay attention, i've changed a bit your regexp to permit a space char in the phone and a space char between phone and extension, and add the ternary to get 0 when no extesion

Answer (score 0):

From you example it looks like it fails when nothing found as ext.

A solution is to cast to int `$extension` like this:

```
$extension = intval($extension); //If nothing found will be 0
```

After this we are sure that we have an `integer` and we can change the if statement to:

```
|| $extension === 0)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pns = <<< LOL
941-751-6550 ext 2204
(941) 751-6550 ext 2204
(941)751-6550 ext 2204
9417516550 ext 2204
941-751-6550 e 2204
941-751-6550 ext 2204 
941-751-6550 extension 2204
941-751-6550 x2204
(941) 751-6550
(941)7516550
941-751-6550
941-751-6550
LOL;

preg_match_all('/^([(\d )\-]+)\s?(?:e.*?|x.*?)?(\d+)?$/sim', $pns, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    $phone = preg_replace('#[\-\(\)\s]#','', $matches[1][$i]);
    $extension = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#','', $matches[2][$i]);
    if ($phone == '9417516550' && $extension == '2204') {
             echo "PASS: phone: $phone ext: $extension\n";
    } else {
             echo "FAIL: phone: $phone ext: 0\n";
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
FAIL: phone: 9417516550 ext: 0
FAIL: phone: 9417516550 ext: 0
FAIL: phone: 9417516550 ext: 0
FAIL: phone: 9417516550 ext: 0
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/EsaP72)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you're better off stripping the non-numeric characters, then splitting off anything after the first 10 as the extension. It's conceptually equivalent, but more straightforward and foolproof, and more efficient than running through multiple regexes, which are inherently slow.

```
foreach($tests as $test){
    $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $test);
    $extension = substr($phone,10);
    $phone = substr($phone,0,10);
    if(empty($extension)){
         $extension = '0';
    }
    if ($phone == '9417516550'
        && ($extension == '2204'
            || $extension == '0')) {
                echo "PASS: phone: $phone ext: $extension<br />\n";
    } else {
        echo "FAIL: phone: $phone ext: $extension<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 2204
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 0
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 0
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 0
PASS: phone: 9417516550 ext: 0
```